# How to analyse data when it comes from different conditions

Tags: anova

In my experiment, I am varying 4 different parameters (`side`, `eccentricity`, `latency` and `duration`), and for each of these conditions I have 2 or 4 values (e.g., `eccentricity` can be `5 deg` or `10 deg`, `side` can be `right`, `left`, `bottom`, `top`, and so on). I want to compare the rates for `5 deg` vs. `10 deg` and for both of them, the data can be either from `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left`. My concern is that if I just add rate across all sides, the `side` condition will affect my `eccentricity` condition and my error will be quite high. So if I cannot sum the data from the sides, how can I compare the means of `5 deg` vs. `10 deg`, while taking the sides into account?

Comment: Why not just include `side` as another factor in your ANOVA?

Comment: @gung, i think that he's struggling with the fact that side is not ordinal, unlike other variables, but i agree that it could be added to ANOVA as a dummy

Comment: @gung is it possible to include side as another factor in ANOVA if I am using MATLAB?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the ANOVA2 function can be used to do a 2-way anova.

Comment: I haven't used MATLAB in a long time, so I don't know the code, but certainly it will let you do multiple-factor ANOVAs.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a multiple regression where you have 3 ordinal or even cardinal variables: `eccentricity`, `latency` and `duration`.

The `side` will have 3 dummy variables: `right`, `top` and `bottom`. if all of them are 0, then it's `left` etc.

Run the model like: `rate ~ (eccentricity + latency + duration) * (right + top + bottom)` in Wilkinson notation (as in  Wilkinson, G. N., and C. E. Rogers. Symbolic description of factorial models for analysis of variance. J. Royal Statistics Society 22, pp. 392–399, 1973).

Now you can compare the coefficients of `latency` or its interaction with `side`.